# Cant change value of input box when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I'm trying to make a simple JavaScript calculator.Right now I'm just trying to change the input box to display the button I clicked, but I'm having trouble figuring out why its not working. here's my code.

```js
var display = document.getElementById('display');

function toScreen(x) {
 display ='';
 display.textContent = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Javascript Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
   <form>
    <input type="text" id="display" disabled>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="C" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('c')">
    <input type="button" value="CE" id="keys" onclick="clearEntry('c')">
    <input type="button" value="x^2" id="keys" onclick="powerOf('c')">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('+')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="9" id="keys" onclick='toScreen("9")'>
    <input type="button" value="8" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('8')">
    <input type="button" value="7" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('7')">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('-')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="6" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('6')">
    <input type="button" value="5" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('5')">
    <input type="button" value="4" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('4')">
    <input type="button" value="x" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('x')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="3" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('3')">
    <input type="button" value="2" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('2')">
    <input type="button" value="1" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('1')">
    <input type="button" value="/" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('/')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="0" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('0')">
    <input type="button" value="." id="keys" onclick="toScreen('.')">
    <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="equal()">
   </form> 
   <h3>Javascript Calculator</h3>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With input-like elements, assign to `.value`, not to `.textContent`, to change their value

Comment: `display =''` is wrong here - you are assigning a string to a variable that you treat as an object afterwards.

Comment: Is `toScreen()` supposed to add the character to the screen or overwrite the screen with the character?

Answer (score 1):

I have attached the working code here. If you wish to just replace the text in input remove `+` from the function.

```js
var display = document.getElementById('display');

function toScreen(x) {
 display.value += x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Javascript Calculator</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
   <form>
    <input type="text" id="display" disabled>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="C" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('c')">
    <input type="button" value="CE" id="keys" onclick="clearEntry('c')">
    <input type="button" value="x^2" id="keys" onclick="powerOf('c')">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('+')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="9" id="keys" onclick='toScreen("9")'>
    <input type="button" value="8" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('8')">
    <input type="button" value="7" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('7')">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('-')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="6" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('6')">
    <input type="button" value="5" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('5')">
    <input type="button" value="4" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('4')">
    <input type="button" value="x" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('x')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="3" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('3')">
    <input type="button" value="2" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('2')">
    <input type="button" value="1" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('1')">
    <input type="button" value="/" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('/')">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="0" id="keys" onclick="toScreen('0')">
    <input type="button" value="." id="keys" onclick="toScreen('.')">
    <input type="button" value="=" id="equal" onclick="equal()">
   </form> 
   <h3>Javascript Calculator</h3>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `display.value += x;` instead

Answer (score 0):

approch 1:
    function toScreen(x) {

```
        document.getElementById("display").value= x;
}
```

approach 2:
if you want to keep display outiside of the method then you have to keep whole code below( i.e before body end tag). As per you current code you are trying access the element before dom is getting loaded
var display = document.getElementById("display");

code :

```
    var display = document.getElementById("display");

    function toScreen(x) {
        display.value =x;

    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting in console.

Comment: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json

Comment: I download this and the error will go away until I close my webpage, but when I re-open it the error comes back in the console??

Answer (score 0):

Lets see the problem with the code

In following statement you are assigning the text object by finding element and it is fine.

```
var display = document.getElementById('display');
```

In following statement you are overriding text object with empty string, means there is not textbox object in display variable and here is the problem.

```
display ='';
```

What you need to do to clear text box content is

```
display.value='';
```

The textContent property sets or returns the text content of the specified node and not to play with text box value. You need to use value property instead.

so final code must be like below

```
var display = document.getElementById('display');

    function toScreen(x) {

        display.value ='';//Even this is not required because already over writing text in following statement

        display.value = x;

    }
```

Comment: Please share whole script.